# SSAS : Errors in the metadata manager

Tags: ssas

I am working on an SSAS project which is deployed at several customers and which works well for the majority. the problem is that there are clients for whom access to the cube from Excel is blocked by having this error message:
*Errors in the metadata manager. An error occurred when loading the 'Compta' cube, from the file, '\?\E:\SQL\MSAS13.CEGIBI\OLAP\Data\Bi_AnalysisServices.33.db\Compta test.1189.cub.xml'.*
the problem disappears when you connect to the Analysis server from SQL Management Studio.

I Tried to stop Analysis Servies ,delete the instance and redeploy it and it didn't work.
Does anyone has a solution for this problem ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the origin of the problem.
its a program that restarts SSAS Services to refresh memory :

```
net stop MSSQLServerOLAPService
net start MSSQLServerOLAPService
```

that script doesn't work correctly and u need to open SSMS to have acces to the cube via EXCEL.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced issues mentioning the xml files in the SSAS folder. In some cases, the issue has gone away after the folder is excluded from anti-virus scans. The theory was that the anti-virus application is scanning the files agressively and this may have interfered with the SSAS process. So, in our deployments the recommendation is to exclude the SSAS data folders from the anti-virus application.

There are MS recommendations about SQL Server exclusions:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-choose-antivirus-software-to-run-on-computers-that-are-running-sql-server-feda079b-3e24-186b-945a-3051f6f3a95b

> The directory that holds Analysis Services data

> The directory that holds Analysis Services temporary files that are used during Analysis Services processing

Refering the official MS docs general helps in getting the Server folks to agree to exclude the OLAP DATA folders from the anti-virus application.